# Choosing individual colors for a cell in a table using kable

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

Is it possible to choose your own color for a cell when creating a table using kable.
In the folowing code from the kable documentation, it shows how you can choose a spectrum (from a couple of options) of colors for a row or column, but I want 1 color for 1 cell. That I can export to a PDF, using knitr.

```
vs_dt <- iris[1:10, ]
vs_dt[5] <- cell_spec(vs_dt[[5]], color = "white", bold = T,
background = spec_color(1:10, end = 0.9, option = "D", direction = -1))
15
kbl(vs_dt, booktabs = T, escape = F, align = "c")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you would only need 1 color for 1 cell, you can specify the row and column of that cell to be modified.

```
vs_dt <- iris[1:10, ]

#needed as they are factors
vs_dt$Species <- as.character(vs_dt$Species)

#only the first entry of the Species column
vs_dt[1,5] <- cell_spec(vs_dt[1,5], color = "white", bold = T,
      background = "red")

# you can also change some of them excluding the cell.
vs_dt[2:10,5] <- cell_spec(vs_dt[2:10,5], bold = T)

kbl(vs_dt, booktabs = T, escape = F, align = "c")
```

Comment: This defintly works, so thank you for that. I do have another question though. Am i limited to a specific color pallet? It seems that for example the color like "darkgoldenrod2" or "darkslategray3" are not working. It seems to be the same regardles if I change `color` or `background`.

Comment: I tried `"darkgoldenrod"` and `"darkslategray"` as the arguments and they showed up in my case. Probably omitting the number after the name makes it work. You can also put hex colors such as `"#000000"` as background and it will work as well.

Comment: That's a suprising discovery to me, thank you! It's quite limiting as I was trying to create something where people could choose their own colors, and I rather not limit that choice. Do you have an idea of how to bypass this? I basically want to use the color that correspont to a plot, to highlight something in a table.

Comment: Or is the problem with using the `kable` package? I looked for other packages but they seem to all have HTML outputs. So I believe that is not going to work ideally for a knitr project that exports to PDF